# Switch statement with returns -- code correctness

Tags: c, switch-statement, correctness

Let's say I have code in C with approximately this structure:

```
switch (something)
{
    case 0:
      return "blah";
      break;

    case 1:
    case 4:
      return "foo";
      break;

    case 2:
    case 3:
      return "bar";
      break;

    default:
      return "foobar";
      break;
}
```

Now obviously, the `break`s are not necessary for the code to run correctly, but it sort of looks like bad practice if I don't put them there to me.

What do you think? Is it fine to remove them? Or would you keep them for increased "correctness"?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Remove the `break` statements. They aren't needed and perhaps some compilers will issue **"Unreachable code"** warnings.

Comment: The same applies with other unconditional control-jumping statements, like `continue` or `goto` - it's idiomatic to use them in place of the `break`.

Answer (score 45):

I would take a different tack entirely.  Don't RETURN in the middle of the method/function.  Instead, just put the return value in a local variable and send it at the end.

Personally, I find the following to be more readable:

```
String result = "";

switch (something) {
case 0:
  result = "blah";
  break;
case 1:
  result = "foo";
  break;
}

return result;
```

Comment: +1 because I would do the same and do not understand why someone would downrate this solution. I dislike having jumpy code.

Comment: The "One Exit" philosophy makes sense in C, where you need to ensure things are cleaned up correctly. Considering in C++ you can be yanked out of the function at any point by an exception, the one exit philosophy isn't really useful in C++.

Comment: In theory this is a great idea, but it frequently requires extra control blocks that can hamper readability.

Comment: As the function pretty much does just that, I personally think returning inside the switch is more readable.

Comment: The primary reason why I do things this way, is that in longer functions it is very easy to miss the exit vector when scanning through code.  However, when the exit is always at the end then it's easier to quickly grasp what's going on.

Comment: Well, that, and return blocks in the middle of code just remind me of GOTO abuse.

Comment: @Chris : In longer functions, I totally agree - but that usually speaks to bigger problems, so refactor it out.  In many cases, it's a trivial function returning on a switch, and it's very clear what is supposed to happen, so don't waste brain power on tracking an extra variable.

Comment: For simple functions I'd agree entirely with the "one entrance/one exit" policy, but certainly not as a general rule. In more complicated situations, it can lead to solutions that involve lots of redundant checks that can be avoided by simply returning early.

Comment: There is no string object in C. I think that should be char *.

Comment: It's more efficient without the string, although negligible. Still, if the switch is at the end of the function, it's not too hard to miss the return, especially with comments. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: If your function is so big that you will miss a return statement in the switch cases it's probably time to refactor the function into smaller ones. Assigning and returning at the bottom also introduces mutable variables which require you to read the *entire function* to understand what it returns.

Comment: Great solution! It solves MisraC2012-16.3 also.

Comment: I consider "one exit" to be an Anti-pattern from history.

Answer (score 8):

I would remove them. In my book, dead code like that should be considered errors because it makes you do a double-take and ask yourself "How would I ever execute that line?"

Answer (score 7):

Remove them.  It's idiomatic to return from `case` statements, and it's "unreachable code" noise otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I would remove the returns and keep the breaks.  I would use the switch statement to assign a value to a variable.  Then return that variable after the switch statement.

Though this is an arguable point I've always felt that good design and encapsulation means one way in and one way out.  It is much easier to guarantee the logic and you don't accidentally miss cleanup code based on the cyclomatic complexity of your function.

One exception:  Returning early is okay if a bad parameter is detected at the beginning of a function--before any resources are acquired.

Comment: Might be good for this particular `switch`, but not necessarily best in general. Well, lets say the switch statement inside a function precedes another 500 lines of code which holds valid only when certain cases are `true`. What's the point of executing all that extra code for the cases that do not need to execute it; isn't it better to just `return` inside the `switch` for those `case`s?

Answer (score 5):

I'd normally write the code without them. IMO, dead code tends to indicate sloppiness and/or lack of understanding.

Of course, I'd also consider something like:

```
char const *rets[] = {"blah", "foo", "bar"};

return rets[something];
```

Edit: even with the edited post, this general idea can work fine:

```
char const *rets[] = { "blah", "foo", "bar", "bar", "foo"};

if ((unsigned)something < 5)
    return rets[something]
return "foobar";
```

At some point, especially if the input values are sparse (e.g., 1, 100, 1000 and 10000), you want a sparse array instead. You can implement that as either a tree or a map reasonably well (though, of course, a switch still works in this case as well).

Comment: Edited the post to reflect why this solution wouldn't work well.

Comment: @your edit: Yes, but it would take more memory, etc. IMHO the switch is the simplest way, which is what I want in such a small function (it does just the switch).

Comment: @houbysoft: look carefully before you conclude that it'll take extra memory. With a typical compiler, using "foo" twice (for example) will use two pointers to a single block of data, not replicate the data. You can also expect shorter code. Unless you have a *lot* of repeated values, it will often save memory overall.

Comment: true. I'll still stick to my solution though because the list of values is very long, and a switch just seems nicer.

Comment: Indeed, the more elegant and efficient answer to a problem like this, when the switch values are contiguous and the data type homogeneous, is to use an array avoid a switch altogether.

Answer (score 5):

If you have "lookup" type of code, you could package the switch-case clause in a method by itself.

I have a few of these in a "hobby" system I'm developing for fun:

```
private int basePerCapitaIncomeRaw(int tl) {
    switch (tl) {
        case 0:     return 7500;
        case 1:     return 7800;
        case 2:     return 8100;
        case 3:     return 8400;
        case 4:     return 9600;
        case 5:     return 13000;
        case 6:     return 19000;
        case 7:     return 25000;
        case 8:     return 31000;
        case 9:     return 43000;
        case 10:    return 67000;
        case 11:    return 97000;
        default:    return 130000;
    }
}
```

(Yep. That's GURPS space...)

I agree with others that you should in most cases avoid more than one return in a method, and I do recognize that this one might have been better implemented as an array or something else. I just found switch-case-return to be a pretty easy match to a lookup table with a 1-1 correlation between input and output, like the above thing (role-playing games are full of them, I am sure they exist in other "businesses" as well) :D

On the other hand, if the case-clause is more complex, or something happens after the switch-statement, I wouldn't recommend using return in it, but rather set a variable in the switch, end it with a break, and return the value of the variable in the end.

(On the ... third? hand... you can always refactor a switch into its own method... I doubt it will have an effect on performance, and it wouldn't surprise me if modern compilers could even recognize it as something that could be inlined...)

Answer (score 4):

Keep the breaks - you're less likely to run into trouble if/when you edit the code later if the breaks are already in place.

Having said that, it's considered by many (including me) to be bad practice to return from the middle of a function. Ideally a function should have one entry point and one exit point.

Answer (score 4):

> *What do you think? Is it fine to remove them? Or would you keep them for increased "correctness"?*

It is fine to remove them. Using `return`  is **exactly** the scenario where  `break` should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

I would say remove them and define a default: branch.

Comment: If there's no sensible default then you should not define a default.

Comment: there is one, and I defined one, I just didn't put it in the question, edited it now.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/default-case
opinionated, but reason being you should define a default case for clarity, even if that default is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be better to have an array with

```
arr[0] = "blah"
arr[1] = "foo"
arr[2] = "bar"
```

and do `return arr[something];`?

If it's about the practice in general, you should keep the `break` statements in the switch. In the event that you don't need `return` statements in the future, it lessens the chance it will fall through to the next `case`.

Comment: Edited the post to reflect why this solution wouldn't work well.

Answer (score 2):

For "correctness", single entry, single exit blocks are a good idea. At least they were when I did my computer science degree. So I would probably declare a variable, assign to it in the switch and return once at the end of the function

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. The consensus from most of these answers seems to be that the redundant `break` statement is unnecessary clutter. On the other hand, I read the `break` statement in a switch as the 'closing' of a case. `case` blocks that don't end in a `break` tend to jump out at me as potential fall though bugs.

I know that that's not how it is when there's a `return` instead of a `break`, but that's how my eyes 'read' the case blocks in a switch, so I personally would prefer that each `case` be paired with a `break`.  But many compilers do complain about the `break` after a `return` being superfluous/unreachable, and apparently I seem to be in the minority anyway.

So get rid of the `break` following a `return`.

NB: all of this is ignoring whether violating the single entry/exit rule is a good idea or not.  As far as that goes, I have an opinion that unfortunately changes depending on the circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

I say remove them. If your code is so unreadable that you need to stick breaks in there 'to be on the safe side', you should reconsider your coding style :)

Also I've always prefered not to mix breaks and returns in the switch statement, but rather stick with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I personally tend to lose the `break`s. Possibly one source of this habit is from programming window procedures for Windows apps:

```
LRESULT WindowProc (HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
            return sizeHandler (...);
        case WM_DESTROY:
            return destroyHandler (...);
        ...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I personally find this approach a lot simpler, succinct and flexible than declaring a return variable set by each handler, then returning it at the end. Given this approach, the `break`s are redundant and therefore should go - they serve no useful purpose (syntactically or IMO visually) and only bloat the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ***break***s are there for a purpose. It is to keep the 'ideology' of programming alive. If we are to just 'program' our code without logical coherence perhaps it would be readable to you now, but try tomorrow. Try explaining it to your boss. Try running it on Windows 3030.

Bleah, the idea is very simple:

---

```
Switch ( Algorithm )
{

 case 1:
 {
   Call_911;
   Jump;
 }**break**;
 case 2:
 {
   Call Samantha_28;
   Forget;
 }**break**;
 case 3:
 {
   Call it_a_day;
 }**break**;

Return thinkAboutIt?1:return 0;

void Samantha_28(int oBed)
{
   LONG way_from_right;
   SHORT Forget_is_my_job;
   LONG JMP_is_for_assembly;
   LONG assembly_I_work_for_cops;

   BOOL allOfTheAbove;

   int Elligence_says_anyways_thinkAboutIt_**break**_if_we_code_like_this_we_d_be_monkeys;

}
// Sometimes Programming is supposed to convey the meaning and the essence of the task at hand. It is // there to serve a purpose and to keep it alive. While you are not looking, your program is doing  // its thing. Do you trust it?
// This is how you can...
// ----------
// **Break**; Please, take a **Break**;
```

/* Just a minor question though. How much coffee have you had while reading the above? I.T. **Breaks** the system sometimes */

Answer (score 0):

Exit code at one point. That provides better readability to code. Adding return statements (Multiple exits) in between will make debugging difficult .

Answer (score -2):

Simply define variable and return it at last of the switch statement and we can also remove default statement by  setting variable= default value.

****Ex:****

```
switch(someVariable)
{
case 'a':
 return a;
 break;
case 'b':
 return b;
 break;
default:
 return c;
}
```

****solution:****

```
    $result = c; //for default value
    switch(someVariable)
    {
    case 'a':
     $result = a;
     break;
    case 'b':
     $result = b;
     break;
    }
    return $result; //simply return $result
```

- This will lead to reduce your return statement.

Comment: How is your solution *significantly* different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3065464/10871073), posted over 11 years ago?

Comment: It is completely different brother. here I have passed default statement in variable itself and atlast returned.