# Using break statement even though previous line results in exit

Tags: programming-languages, readability

I was reading through some code (C, if it makes a difference to anyone) today and got curious about a switch-block.

```
switch (c_type) {
case -1:
    some_function(some_var);
    break;
[...]
default:
    abort();
}
```

Now, this is a perfectly simple switch-block. It's the `some_function(some_var)`-call I'm curious about: If you, the programmer, is absolutely, positively, super duper sure that the call will result in the process exiting, do you still put the break-statement underneath even though it is completely unnecessary? Would you say that it is best-practice?

Comment: Pretty much an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065438/switch-statement-with-returns-code-correctness/3065451#3065451

Comment: Oops! My bad. And I even searched for an answer beforehand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say best practice would be to have a bomb-out `assert()` below the function call.  This serves a dual purpose: it documents the fact that this point in the runtime should be unreachable, and it produces an error message if the code somehow **does** reach that spot.

Comment: I was going to say the same as Mark, but this is actually a much better response.

Answer (score 3):

Leave the break in there.  It doesn't matter what *you* are sure about: you write your programs for other humans to read, and the break makes it clear that the given case is completely separate from the case that follows.

Even though you could be absolutely certain about the code today, the specification may change tomorrow and `some_function` won't exit anymore.  Nothing in specifications is certain (in my experience anyway).

Comment: Mark is correct:  Knowing what the code does *today* is no guarantee it will always do the same thing in the future.  Write code defensively to reduce future maintenance costs.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm super-duper-super-sure that the call would result in the process exiting, I'd stick an assert in just for that.

That way, if someone modifies the function and it doesn't always-terminate, the bug will be caught pretty much the first time it occurs.

EDIT: Beaten, with pretty much the same answer too :/

Answer (score 0):

It's always best practice to end every case statement with a break or return, unless you want it to fall through to the next.