# Can I put a return statement inside a switch statement?

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement, return

Am I allowed to have a `switch` statement which decides what to return? For example, I want to return something different based on what my random generator come up with. Eclipse is giving me an error wanting me to put the `return` statement outside the `switch`.

My code:

```
public String wordBank() { //Error here saying: "This method must return a type of string"
    String[] wordsShapes = new String[10];
    wordsShapes[1] = "square";
    wordsShapes[2] = "circle";
    wordsShapes[3] = "cone";
    wordsShapes[4] = "prisim";
    wordsShapes[5] = "cube";
    wordsShapes[6] = "cylinder";
    wordsShapes[7] = "triangle";
    wordsShapes[8] = "star";
    wordsShapes[9] = "moon";
    wordsShapes[10] = "paralellogram";

    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(11);

    if (i == 0) {
        i = rand.nextInt(11);
    }

    switch (i) {
    case 1:
        return wordsShapes[1].toString();
    case 2:
        return wordsShapes[2].toString();
    case 3:
        return wordsShapes[3].toString();
    case 4:
        return wordsShapes[4].toString();
    case 5:
        return wordsShapes[5].toString();
    case 6:
        return wordsShapes[6].toString();
    case 7:
        return wordsShapes[7].toString();
    case 8:
        return wordsShapes[8].toString();
    case 9:
        return wordsShapes[9].toString();
    case 10:
        return wordsShapes[10].toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch statement with returns -- code correctness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065438/switch-statement-with-returns-code-correctness)

Comment: You've declared an array of 10 String objects, but you've assigned a String to the *ELEVENTH* position in the array (wordsShapes[10]) - array indices are 0-(n-1), not 1-n.  I'm surprised the compiler didn't generate an error because of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
return wordsShapes[i].toString();
```

This way you can avoid the switch and all.

Answer (score 6):

You can put `return` inside `switch` but you don't need to use `switch` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that you have return statements inside the `switch` statement, which are perfectly fine, but you have no return *after* the switch statement.  If your switch statement completes without returning, what will happen now?

The rules of Java require that all paths through a value-returning function encounter a `return` statement.  In your case, even though *you* know the value of `i` will always be of a value that will cause a `return` from the switch, the Java compiler isn't smart enough to determine that.

(ASIDE: By the way, you didn't actually prevent the value 0 from being generated; maybe your `if` should be a `while`.)

ADDENDUM:  In case you are interested, here's an implementation.  See http://ideone.com/IpIwis for the live example.

```
import java.util.Random;
class Main {
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private static final String[] SHAPES = {
        "square", "circle", "cone", "prism", "cube", "cylinder", "triangle",
        "star", "moon", "parallelogram"
    };

    public static String randomShapeWord() {
        return SHAPES[random.nextInt(SHAPES.length)];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(randomShapeWord());
        }
    }
}
```

Note the best practice of having the random number generator defined outside the function.

Comment: is there an `else if` like statement I should use or just `return null`?

Comment: There is a `default` case in Java.  However, see Ramon's answer for what you _should_ do. :)

Comment: Thank you for the note about the if statement didn't catch that : )

Comment: No problem.  It's best, though, to _embrace_ the zero, not avoid it.  Index your shape names starting at 0, then you won't need a special game.  I added a worked-out example for you.  Have fun with it.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement will return from the entire function in which it is used.So I think it is good that no other useful lines of code must be there below the switch if you want to use the return statement in the switch.