# Is it legal to return an expression of type void?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

This compiles without any warnings.

Is this legal in C and C++ or does it just work in gcc and clang?

If it is legal, is it some new thing after C99?

```
void f(){}

void f2(){
    return f();
}
```

**Update**

as "Rad Lexus" suggested I tried this:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -c x.c 
x.c: In function ‘f2’:
x.c:7:9: warning: ISO C forbids ‘return’ with expression, in function returning void [-Wpedantic]
  return f();
```

---

```
$ clang -Wall -Wpedantic -c x.c 
x.c:7:2: warning: void function 'f2' should not return void expression [-Wpedantic]
        return f();
        ^      ~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

---

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -c x.cc
(no errors)
```

---

```
$ clang -Wall -Wpedantic -c x.cc
(no errors)
```

**Update**

Someone asked how this construction is helping. Well is more or less syntactic sugar. Here is one good example:

```
void error_report(const char *s){
    printf("Error %s\n", s);
    exit(0);
}

void process(){
   if (step1() == 0)
      return error_report("Step 1");

   switch(step2()){
   case 0: return error_report("Step 2 - No Memory");
   case 1: return error_report("Step 2 - Internal Error");
   }

   printf("Processing Done!\n");
}
```

Comment: Voted to re-open; proposed duplicate was for C++ only. This is also tagged C. (C and C++ differ considerably in their use of `void`).

Comment: So you're asking for C or C++? Pick a language.

Comment: Note: with both `gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c99` and `-std=c11`, you get a warning: "warning: ISO C forbids 'return' with expression, in function returning void [-Wpedantic]".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Can I ask about C, C++ and Java at the same time as well? ;-)

Comment: @RadLexus clang outright rejects this.

Comment: How are you going to use that function with [tag:c++]?

Comment: @FUZxxl: thanks for trying with clang. What's the exact error? At least it shows OP's statement that "it works" in gcc and clang is not true – for gcc, it depends on what flags you compile it with.

Comment: @DevSolar :D Well, I'll state that more clear. IMO it's legit to ask about a feature that exists in both C and C++. Usually those features behave similarly in both languages. If not, a good answer would describe the diffefence.

Comment: You don't need to use 'return' if 'exit(0)' exists in 'error_report' function

Comment: One strange thing: `sparse`, a static analyser (I.e. tool designed to catch more errors than your average compiler, this one built to help analyse Linux kernel), not only supports this construct, but explicitly calls it "allowed in C99" in its documentation. No idea why, given that it explicitly isn't.

Comment: @RadLexus Try it for yourself. I don't have a clang around right now.

Comment: @FUZxxl: when I asked I was behind a gcc machine so I tried. I assumed you had a clang at hand since you stated that it rejected it. No sweat though; I'm behind a 'good' machine now and clang indeed says the same. Nick already ran that test as well.

Comment: this line: `return error_report("Step 1");` and the following calls to `error_report()` have a couple of problems.  1) error_report() always executes the `exit()` function, so it never returns.  2) the return type from `error_report()` is `void`, so it should never return anything, even if the call to `exit()` were not always executed.

Comment: If I use gcc to compile and one of the parameters: `-std=gnu99` the statements are accepted with no warnings.  If I use gcc to compile with one of the parameters: `-std=c99`, the there are several warnings output

Comment: `-gnu99` is Gnu C "extension". You can use several non standard things, for example Pascal-like function inside function.

Comment: my 5 cents for Java - return void is not supported.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**C11**, 6.8.6.4 "The `return` statement":

> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

**No**, you may not use an expression, even if it is of `void` type.

From the foreword of the same document:

> Major changes in the second edition included:
>
> [...]
>
> - `return` without expression not permitted in function that returns a value (and vice versa)

So this was a change from C89 -> C99 (the second edition of the language standard), and has been that way ever since.

---

**C++14**, 6.6.3 "The `return` statement":

> A return statement with an expression of non-void type can be used only in functions returning a value [...]
>   A return statement with an expression of type void can be used only in functions with a return type of cv
>   void; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller.

**Yes**, you may use an expression *if* it is of void type (that's been valid since C++98).

Comment: "A return statement with an expression of type void can be used only in functions with a return type of cv void"  Why would anyone want to write such nonsense code though? Rather than just writing `void f2(){  f(); }`. Seems like there must be a rationale for it somewhere, even though it is C++?

Comment: @Lundin: Templates? I assume. Looks like <= C99 allowed it as well, and C++ probably just copied that behaviour.

Comment: But pre C99 I believe it caused undefined behavior. This doesn't seem to be the case in C++. Why would anyone use a void template then, if that is even allowed?

Comment: @Lundin: Pfff... don't ask me. I don't specify the standard, I just implement it. ;-) (That's why I have the PDFs ready at hand and know roughly where to look.)

Comment: @Lundin: It allows e.g. `if (cond) return f() ;` instead of `if (cond) { f() ; return ; }`

Comment: @Lundin: In C++, mostly for templates.  If the return type of `f` and `f2` are arguments to the template, being able to write `return f();` without having to special case `void` is handy.  (obviously this *particular* sample code doesn't really work as a template - but with more complex code it can be useful - see the `futures` stuff for example.

Comment: As Mohit's answer correctly quotes, the item "return without expression not permitted in function that returns a value" is under Foreward paragraph 7 "Major changes in the **second** edition" not paragraph 6 "This third edition ... [m]ajor changes". Second edition was C99, which changed C89/90 only for return *without* expression; return *with* expression in a void function was prohibited since C89/90, when void was first introduced. @Lundin before C99 return without expression in a **non**-void function *and the caller trying to use the value* was UB.

Comment: And BTW although official C99 cost money and is now withdrawn, the first draft for 'C0x' (which ended up as C11)  was C99 with the three Technical Corrigenda applied, as WG14 document n1256, which can be obtained at no cost in the obvious place.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for pointing out. Corrected the quote.

Comment: @MartinBonner That doesn't explain why you would ever want to use a void template though. Why should you have to write a special case for void, if no sane person would ever use that type for templates? It doesn't make any sense to allow void for templates, as there are no operators that work with the void type. Seems like complete nonsense to me, void is always an incomplete type. g++ agrees, "In instantiation of 't foo(t*) [with t = void]': required from here error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'"

Comment: @Lundin:  The "futures" stuff I referred executes a function possibly asynchronously.  There is a member to wait for and return the result of the function or throw any exceptions the function threw.  If the function happens to return void (because you are executing it for its side effects rather than its result), then this member still waits, and throws exceptions, but returns void.

Comment: In particular, in the case where the function is executed synchronously, the member will just `return external_function(args...);`

Comment: Not sure if it's legal in C++, but using `void` as template parameter could be useful to express a *set* as a *map* where the *value* type is *unit* (zero-sized).

Comment: @CodesInChaos C++11 gives you `std::unordered_set` anyway, better than rolling your own hashset unless performance is truly an issue. I know that in some set implementations, though, it can be better to have the value type be a boolean or some other flag type to provide some slight optimizations (i.e. in concurrent sets, there are advantages to still having the spot around even after the item is technically "removed" from the set to allow for lock-free behavior).

Comment: This is very useful if you consider [switch statements with returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065438/switch-statement-with-returns-code-correctness). In a `void` function containing a `switch` statement, instead of writing `case X: f(); break;` you can write `case X: return f();` and not have to worry about `case`s falling through if you miss the `break;`.

Comment: This possibility is super-handy when forwarding lambdas when you can't easily infer its result type. Something like: `template<class F> auto run(F&& lambda) { return lambda(...some_args...); }`. Now, `F` may or may not return `void`. I am happy that I don't need to specialize this function for that corner case!

Answer (score 16):

This code is allowed in `C++` but not allowed in `C`

From [Return statement @ cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return)

> In a function returning void, the return statement with expression can
>   be used, if the expression type is void.

---

OTOH in C11 specs draft n1570:

**Major changes in the second edition included:**

> return without expression not permitted in function that returns a
>   value (and vice versa)

(`return` with expression not permitted in function that returns a `void`)

and 6.8.6.4 return

> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function
>   whose return type is void. A return statement without an expression
>   shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

(even if the expression evaluates to `void`)

Comment: It would be better to quote the C++ standard and possibly document since which version the construction is allowed. cppreference is not a very dependable source, many code samples have bugs.

Comment: @chqrlie Can you give me a link to a page where code sample is wring @ en.cppreference?

Comment: @MohitJain: just an example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat  compiled with gcc 4.6: 
`main.cpp:31:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`.  Not an error since C99, but bad style.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks. I don't have C++ specs, I use latest drafts and en.cppreference for my reference whenever I need it.

Comment: @MohitJain: The C++ latest drafts are close enough.  The source code is actually available on github! I wish the C and C++ Standards were publicly available for free.  cppreference is actually very well documented, my earlier judgement may have reflected my impressions based on the French translation.  Any visible bugs can be fixed as they are spotted.

Answer (score 5):

C++ allows something like that:

```
void f() 
{
    return void();
}
```

While C does not. That's why a warning is issued if you compile it a ISO C rather than ISO C++. This is formally described as:

> A return statement with an expression of type void can be used only in
>   functions with a return type of cv void

Comment: It looks correct, but standard references for both claims would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

ISO/IEC 9899:201x Committee draft says the following:

> 6.8.6.4 The return statement
>
> Constraints
>
> 1. `return` statement with an expression **shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`**.
>
>    A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a
>      function whose return type is `void`.

So, it is forbidden in C.

---

You need to use `-pedantic` switch to `gcc` for it to complain about standard violations:

```
test.c: In function ‘f2’:
test.c:6:12: warning: ISO C forbids ‘return’ with expression, in function returning void 
            [-Wpedantic]
     return f();
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard C does not support this construction:

> **C11 6.8.6.4: The `return` statement**
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

No special provisions are added for the special case in the question.  Some C compilers do support this as an extension (`gcc` does, unless instructed to conform to one of the C Standards), but C11 and previous versions consider it a constraint violation.